# Инициализизация статического массива как статическое поле класса с++

Tags: c++, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как инициализировать статический массив в качестве статического поля класса в С++. Ведь инициализация статических полей проводится в глобальной области, а в ней нельзя писать цикл `for` (для того, чтобы через цикл инициализировать каждый элемент).

Comment: поясните: в качестве массива вы используете сишный (`int a[10]`) или вектор `vector<int> a(10)`?

Answer (score 2):

Это вас устроит?

```
struct Test
{
    static int array[10];
    static void out();
};

void Test::out()
{
    for(auto i: array) cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int Test::array[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test::out();
}
```

Или проблема в чем-то ином? тогда поясните, в чем.

Comment: Может инициализацию стоит в out реализовать?

Comment: @JK_Action  Можно, но это уже будет не совсем та инициализация :) Если позарез нужна именно функция - я бы сделал так - еще одно статическое поле, которое представляет собой объект вспомогательного класса, конструктор которого и занимается инициализацией массива.

Answer (score 0):

В С++ массивы в области статической памяти или памяти потока можно инициализировать только списком  константных выражений. Это действие формируется на момент компиляции. Внутри функции можно написать:

```
int n = 1;
int a[2] = {n++, n++};
```

а  для глобального массива или статического поля такое будет неверно. Если нужно инициализировать все или часть элементов нулями. достаточно написать

```
int a[10] = {1,2,3}; // Все остальное - нули 
int b[10] = {};      // Все - нули. Си не позволяет пустой список,для С++ это легально.
```

Если вам нужны не константные значения, придётся определить точку, где будет происходить их присвоение